# Flask ImportError: cannot import name routes

Tags: python, flask

I'm converting a cli application to use a REST api and I've read up on flask and I thought I understood things but apparently not :-D. based on this: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

I have a directory structure:

```
--myApp
  myApp.py
  --APIService
    __init__.py
    WebService.py
```

myApp.py:

```
from APIService import app

app.run(debug = True )
```

**init**:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import routes
```

WebService.py:

```
 from APIService import app

 class WebService(object):
   '''
    classdocs
   '''


   def __init__(self,):
       '''
       Constructor
       '''
       @app.route('/')
       @app.route('/index')
       def index():
           return "Hello, World!"
```

I've tried this a few different ways like renaming app to APIService but I keep circling back to the same error: `APIService\__init__.py", line 5, in <module> from app import routes ImportError: No module named app`

I just don't get what I'm doing wrong here. I did pip install flask so the module is there. I skipped the environment part but that's because I wasn't bothered with running globally for now. anyone have a clue as to what I messed up?

Comment: You need to do "from app import routes" instead of "from app import route"...you have to import routes and not route here..

Comment: ah good catch, I forgot the `s` the error had it though. fixed

Comment: you need to import like this in your __init__ file: "from APIService import routes" instead of "from app import routes".

Comment: making that change give me: `from APIService import routes ImportError: cannot import name routes`

Comment: you have mentioned the complete directory structure above right? Or os there any other file as well? What file are you running for making the app run?

Comment: Yes it's complete you can create a project from what I have and reproduce the problem. There is more in the original but I've set this structure up to reproduce the problem. myApp.py runs the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line inside`APIService\__init__.py`:

```
from app import routes
```

the keyword routes is referencing a separate Python Module inside the `APIService` folder that is named "routes.py" in the Flask Mega Tutorial. It seems like you have renamed the "routes.py" file to "WebService.py" so you can solve the import issue by changing the import line inside`APIService\__init__.py`to:

```
from app import WebService
```